# Retrieving path to current/own bundle

Tags: c++, objective-c, macos, core-foundation, nsbundle

While writing a cross-platform module, I needed a way to retrieve the path to the module directory (so I can access files in the modules folder, like configs and resources). My module, currently compiled as a bundle, is loaded by arbitrary processes. Getting the path of my module is done pretty easily in windows, like so:

```
GetModuleFileName(GetModuleHandle(0), buf, size); // copies the path of the current DLL into buf
```

I haven't been able to find a similar method on OSX. I tried `_NSGetExecutablePath()` but it only retrieves the path of the main program. Also tried [the method here](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/193451-finding-out-executable-location-from-c-program.html).

However, it also gets the path of the main executable. What is the common method for doing so on OSx?

Regards

edit:

grady player showed me the way :) I compiled the following code using NSBundle:

```
/*
    this could be anything apparantly
*/
@interface dummyObject : NSObject
- (void) dummyMethod;
@end

@implementation dummyObject
- (void) dummyMethod {
}
@end

int GetBundlePath(char * buf, int bufSize)
{
    NSString * path = [[NSBundle bundleForClass:[dummyObject class]]bundlePath];
    const char * intString = [path UTF8String];
    int length = strlen(intString);
    int smallestLength = length > bufSize ? bufSize : length;
    memcpy(buf, intString, smallestLength);
    [path release];
    return smallestLength;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[[NSBundle bundleForClass:[thisClass class]]bundlePath];
```

will work for dynamic library...

or if you are looking for your main

```
    [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
```

also bundleURL... see the [NSBundle Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSBundle_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSBundle/bundlePath)

then your resources should be relative to your main bundle.
you can use

```
 [[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath]stringByAppendingPathComponents:@[@"Contents",@"Resources"]];
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I am totally new to everything objective-c related (using c++ otherwise), can you please expand a bit on the first example (i'm pretty sure thats what i want!)?
Specifically, thisClass refers to what - a class instantiated by the returned bundle? I see some do it like this, is this valid? 
NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]];
Afterwards, i would call bundlePath on the returned bundle to retrieve a path to it?

Comment: @Shaggi class is both a class and instance method so any local class or instance... for instance `[MyDog class]` or `[aDog class]` should return the same thing...

Comment: I got it working - thank you so much - updated topic with working example.